# google form allow currently date only on date picker

Tags: validation, datepicker, google-forms

[[image: anyone help pls! I need to disable all date except currently date only available to pick from date]][anyone help pls! I need to disable all date except currently date only available to pick from date]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Forms doesn't support data validation / rules for date pickers.

NOTE: Google Apps Script doesn't support client-side automation for Google Forms.

Reference

- [Set rules for your form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en)